# run test cases in parallel python

Tags: nose, python-multiprocessing

I would like to get some help for running multiple python test cases in parallel using multiprocessing module. I have created a class FooTest with 10 test cases in it (testA, testB...). There is a test case test_foo outside the class.

How can I run all the test cases in parallel using python multiprocessing module? Thanks for the help.

```
import unittest
import time

def setUp():
    print "module setup"

def test_foo():
    pass

class FooTest(unittest.TestCase):

    # preparing to test
    def setUp(self):
        """ Setting up for the test """
        print "FooTest:setUp_:begin"

    # ending the test
    def tearDown(self):
        """Cleaning up after the test"""
        print "FooTest:tearDown_:begin"

    # test routine A
    def testA(self):
        """Test routine A"""
        print "FooTest:testA"
        time.sleep(2)

    # test routine B
    def testB(self):
        """Test routine B"""
        print "FooTest:testB"

    # test routine C
    def testC(self):
        """Test routine C"""
        print "FooTest:testC"

    # test routine D
    def testD(self):
        """Test routine D"""
        print "FooTest:testD"

    # test routine E
    def testE(self):
        """Test routine E"""
        print "FooTest:testE"
        time.sleep(2)

    # test routine F
    def testF(self):
        """Test routine F"""
        print "FooTest:testF"

    # test routine G
    def testG(self):
        """Test routine G"""
        print "FooTest:testG"

    # test routine H
    def testH(self):
        """Test routine H"""
        print "FooTest:testH"

    # test routine I
    def testI(self):
        """Test routine I"""
        print "FooTest:testI"

    # test routine J
    def testJ(self):
        """Test routine J"""
        print "FooTest:testJ"
        time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [nose documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_multiprocess/multiprocess.html), which you can also get by running `nosetests --help`:

> --processes=NUM       Spread test run among this many processes. Set
>   a
>                          number equal to the number of processors or cores in
>                          your machine for best results. Pass a negative number
>                          to have the number of processes automatically set to
>                          the number of cores. Passing 0 means to disable
>                          parallel testing. Default is 0 unless NOSE_PROCESSES
>                          is set. [NOSE_PROCESSES]

So just run `nosetests --processes=-1` to run your tests in parallel using all the cores on your machine.